# How to delete by id using jquery/javascript, Spring?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-boot

I've been wanted to delete the row by its id. 
I've already done "things" in Service, Controller, Listfiles, and the Delete file.

This is the controller

```
  @RequestMapping("/hapussertifikasi")
    public String hapussertifikasi() {
        return ("sertifikasi/hapussertifikasi");
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hapussertifikasi/{angka}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public Map<String, String> hapussertifikasi(@PathVariable("angka") Long angka, Model model) {
        sertifikasisr.hapus(angka);
        // key value
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        // pakai String string karena value key dan value nya string
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(angka);
        map.put("status", "berhasil");
        // DARI BARANG SERVICE
        /*
         * if(brngsr.hapus(angka)) { // key value map.put("status", "berhasil"); }else {
         * map.put("status", "gagal"); }
         */

        return map;
    }
```

This is the Service file

```
 public boolean hapus(Long id) {
        try {
            sertifikasi.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the List File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Nulis table didalam body -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Nama Sertifikasi</td>
                    <td>Penerbit</td>
                    <td>Masa Berlaku</td>
                    <td>#</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="idTbodySertifikasi">
                <tr th:each="item :${keysertifikasi}">
                <td th:text="${item.id}">ID</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.certificate_name}">NamaBarang</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.publisher}">JenisBarang</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.until_year + '-' + item.until_month }">Sampai</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown">
                                More <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="clDropdown" data-value="0"><a href="#">Ubah</a></li>
                                <li class="clDropdown" data-value="1"><a href="#">Hapus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.table-responsive').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
            $('.table-responsive').css("overflow", "inherit");
        });

        $('.table-responsive').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
            $('.table-responsive').css("overflow", "auto");
        });

        $(".clDropdown").click(function() {
            debugger;
            var x = $(this).data('value');
            var angka = $(this).attr('data-idbarang');
            if (x == 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : './ubahsertifikasi',
                    method : 'Get',
                    success : function(model) {
                        debugger;
                        /* jahit model return dari controller ke body modal */
                        $('#idMdlBodyUbahSertifikasi').html(model);
                        /* pop up modalnya */
                        $('#idMdlUbahSertifikasi').modal('show');
                    },
                    error : function(model) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                });
            } else if (x == 1) {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    url : './hapussertifikasi',
                    method : 'Get',
                    success : function(model) {
                        debugger;
                        /* jahit model return dari controller ke body modal */
                        $('#idMdlBodyHapusSertifikasi').html(model);
                        /* pop up modalnya */
                        $('#idMdlHapusSertifikasi').modal('show');
                    },
                    error : function(model) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And lastly this is the delete file where the delete button is placed

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash center" style="font-size: 50px"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="clTulisanHapus center" id="idTulisanHapus">Anda
                    Yakin ingin menghapus Pelatihan?</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-8">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="idBtnHapusBatal" class="btn clBtnMdlHapus">Tidak</button>
            <button type="button" id="idBtnHapusHapus" class="btn clBtnMdlHapus">Ya</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#idBtnHapusHapus').click(function() {
            var angka = $(this).attr('data-id');
            debugger;
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url : '/hapussertifikasi/' + angka,
                type : 'DELETE',

                success : function(model) {
                    debugger;
                    window.location = './sertifikasi'

                },
                error : function(model) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The id is showing ok, but the id values isn't sending to the Controller file.

Comment: `url` should be `'/hapussertifikasi/' + angka`

Comment: Whoops sorry forgot to change it! I've tried(changed) it but still didn't work. Have any idea?

Comment: Hello @PiPio your controller gets invoked and you are not getting the id. is it?

Comment: Yup the Controller isn't getting the id when i print it on the console

Comment: Hi @PatelRomil! I've changed it but still didn't work :3

Comment: is there any error or message

Comment: the error told me error 400 , and the var angka is undefined.?

Comment: when you make the request by click where your debugger goes?

Comment: the button #idBtnHapusHapus works. then it goes to error not the success

Comment: Hello @PiPio var angka is undefined means problem is in `var angka = $(this).attr('data-id');` make sure you get the value here of type Long according to your controller

Comment: @PiPio According to your list file it might be `data-idbarang` instead of data-id, just check it out with attr and let me know

Comment: did you try a static value like `var angka = 1`? just to check if it's a frontend or backend issue

Comment: Okay it's backend issue and i've solved it :) 
Thankyou guys, inspiration just came through lol

Comment: That's great @PiPio issue with type of var or what?

Comment: in the delete file i didn't declare the angka value with the right thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button `<button type="button" id="idBtnHapusHapus" class="btn clBtnMdlHapus">Ya</button>` has no `data-id` attribute, thus when calling `var angka = $(this).attr('data-id');`, `angka` is Nil.

This means you are making a delete request on `/hapussertifikasi/`, which is going to return a 400 error because you aren't passing the required argument (correct syntax would be `/hapussertifikasi/14` where `14` is the id you want to delete.)

Answer (score 0):

hi bro i also face this type of problem .....

after longtime R&D i found a solution , but i don't know why it's working..

try this

```
url : 'hapussertifikasi/' + angka,
```

just remove first `/`sing